# Determinant of a 4x4 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find determinants of matrices A=$\begin{bmatrix}a & 3 & 0 & 5\\0 & b & 0 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & c &3\\ 0&0&0&d \end{bmatrix}$ and B=$\begin{bmatrix}x & y& z & t\\2 & 1 & 1 & 2\\ 2 & 3 & 1 &4\\ 1&3&2&3 \end{bmatrix}$.

I tried to reduce the matrix A by forming a triangular matrix but i could get anything concrete.

Comment: There are many ways to calculate the determinant of a matrix and reducing it to the triangular form is just *one* of them. For example, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 2):

HNT: A: 4th row, then for the minor 3rd column.

Comment: Isn't there any other way because the matrix becomes kind of complex?I was thinking that by turning the matrix to a triangular one we can find the determinant by multiplying the entries in the diagonal.

Comment: What he's saying actually is that the calculations on matrix A turn out to be basically *trivial*, because there's very few non-zero permutations.  ...though I do admit I've never heard the word "verse" used here; "row" is the common one, at least in the US.

Comment: @DanUznanski Oh, row, of course. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: $$\begin{vmatrix}a & 3 & 0 & 5\\0 & b & 0 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & c &3\\ 0&0&0&d \end{vmatrix} = c\begin{vmatrix}a & 3  & 5\\0 & b  & 2\\  0&0&d \end{vmatrix} = cd\begin{vmatrix}a & 4 \\ 0 & b\end{vmatrix} = abcd.$$

For the second one:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x & y& z & t\\2 & 1 & 1 & 2\\ 2 & 3 & 1 &4\\ 1&3&2&3 \end{vmatrix} = x\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\  3 & 1 &4\\ 3&2&3 \end{vmatrix} - y\begin{vmatrix}2  & 1 & 2\\ 2  & 1 &4\\ 1&2&3 \end{vmatrix}+z\begin{vmatrix}2 & 1  & 2\\ 2 & 3  &4\\ 1&3&3 \end{vmatrix} - w\begin{vmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 1&3&2 \end{vmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: for B, don't bother with the triangular matrix; instead, use cofactors on the first row.  This gives you purely numerical calculations, where trying to make something triangular will involve some relatively complicated work with the existing variables.